# Razor Pages - Return Error on Duplicate Name

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm working on a Razor Pages form that takes in a string to create a new customer in a SQL Server Database. I want to make it work so that if the string that is the customer already exists, a prompt comes up that says "This Customer Already Exists". Just to be safe for data integrity.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            int customerCheck = -1; //No Customer ID is -1
            try
            {
                using (var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
                {
                    customerCheck = context.Customer //Tries to grab a Customer with this name
                        .Where(a => a.Name == Customer.name)
                        .Select(b => b.CustomerId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            if(customerCheck == -1)
            {
                _context.Customer.Add(Customer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Customer/List");
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }         
        }
```

This is the code I have so far in my backend. What happens is that when a user tries to create a new customer, the backend of the page tries to see if it can grab a customer ID that correlates to this name. If it can, then the value of customerCheck is not -1, therefore some error should get printed out.

I don't know what methods can be used to do this, so any help would be great!

Comment: Things to lookup:  *AddModelError* and *ValidationSummary*.  Those will get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and it wasn't hard to implement. When a duplicate customer was found in the backend, I create a ModelState.AddModelError object and fill it with a key and a description of the error. Next, in the frontend, I put it within an H3 tag to print it out like so:

**Backend OnPost() Code**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            int customerCheck = 0; //No Customer ID is 0
            try
            {
                using (var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
                {
                    customerCheck = context.Customer //Tries to grab a Customer with this name
                        .Where(a => a.Name == Customer.name)
                        .Select(b => b.CustomerId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            if(customerCheck == 0)
            {
                _context.Customer.Add(Customer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Customer/List");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("DuplicateCustomer", "This Customer Already Exists");
                return Page();
            }
         
        }
```

So on the frontend, it gets implemented like this:

```
<h3 align="center" style="color:yellowgreen">@Html.ValidationMessage("DuplicateCustomer")</h3>
```

When `return Page();` is hit, the page is reloaded and the DuplicateCustomer Error appears.

Comment: but in this case the h3 tag is shown at all times, so for example if the `h3` has a `background-color: red` in the css then a block of red will always be there

Answer (score 1):

At first, glad to hear you have found a solution.

Besides, I think you could also use the Remote Validation to check whether the Customer is exist or not. Check the following sample code:

1. Remote validation in ASP.NET (Core) relies on [Unobtrusive AJAX](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/326/using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-razor-pages), so you will need to install that first. The easiest way to do this is via LibMan. Right click on the lib folder in *wwwroot*, choose **Add** » **Client-side Library**, and then choose jsdelivr as the source, and type in `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive`, click the "Install" button to install the package.
2. In the CreateCustomer.cshtml.cs page, add a Email property and use the `PageRemote` attribute, then, add a handler method to perform the validation.

   ```
        public class CreateCustomerModel : PageModel
        {
            private readonly IRepository _repository;
            public CreateCustomerModel(IRepository repository)
            {
                _repository = repository;
            }

            [PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Email Address already exists", AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken", HttpMethod = "post",PageHandler = "CheckEmail")]
            [BindProperty]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            public void OnGet()
            {
            }

            public IActionResult OnPost()
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //insert data into database.
                }
                return Page();
            }

            #pragma warning disable MVC1001 // Filters cannot be applied to page handler methods.
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            #pragma warning restore MVC1001 // Filters cannot be applied to page handler methods.
            public JsonResult OnPostCheckEmail()
            {
                //query database and check whether the email is exist or not.
                var existingEmails = _repository.GetCustomers().Select(c => c.Email.ToLower()).ToList();
                var valid = !existingEmails.Contains(Email.ToLower());
                return new JsonResult(valid);
            }
   ```
3. In the CreateCustomer.cshtml razor page, add JQuery reference and add a form to enter the values.

   ```
    @page
    @model RazorSample.Pages.CreateCustomerModel
    @{
    }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                @* add other fields *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    }
   ```

After submit the button, the result as below: if the email is exist, it will show the prompt:

[image]

[Note] In the above sample, we are adding the properties in the PageModel (instead of nested model), and use it to validate the field. Because, if using nested object, we might meet the 400 Bad Request result. The 400 error is related to the AntiForgeryToken, if you meet this error, try to ignore validate the AntiForgeryToken or custom add the `__RequestVerificationToken` token at the body or header, check [this link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors).

More detail information about Remote Validation in Razor Pages, check the following articles:

[Remote Validation in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation)

[Improved Remote Validation in Razor Pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/343/improved-remote-validation-in-razor-pages)